# how can I draw a connecting line between the label and the plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my script for the plot,

```
data = data.frame(Kingdom = c("Bacteria", "Archaea"),
                     Total = c(273523, 2616))
sizeRange <- c(0,30)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x=0,y=Kingdom,color=Kingdom)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = Total,alpha=10),colour="blue",stroke=2) + 
  scale_size(range = sizeRange)+ 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"))
```

somebody, please tell me how can I get a connecting line between my y-axis label and the plot
My plot looks like this

[image]

I want something like this[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can manually add segments, but then the alpha of your points will kind of show them.

Here is a try, altought it's not perfect if the x axis expend.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=0,y=Kingdom,color=Kingdom)) +
  # Added the segments here before the points.
  # I tried to alpha it but I can't figure out how to limit the 
  # segment to the point border.
  geom_segment(x = rep(-100,2), xend = rep(0,2), 
               y = c(1, 2), yend = c(1,2),colour="blue", alpha = 10) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Total,alpha=10),colour="blue",stroke=2) +
  scale_size(range = sizeRange)+ 
  theme_bw() + guides(alpha = "none") + # remove alpha from legend.
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A clean alternative would be to label the points directly, and remove the y-axis if wanted.  e.g.:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=0,y=Kingdom,color=Kingdom)) + 
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = Kingdom), vjust = -1,colour="black") + 
  geom_point(aes(size = Total),colour="blue",stroke=2) +
  scale_size(range = sizeRange)+ 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: how can I have these connecting lines straight instead of having them tilted ?

Comment: ggrepel offers lots of options for moving the position - Try `ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = Kingdom), colour="black", nudge_x = -0.01) + `